# Angular textbox default value

Tags: angularjs

Sorry for my English

I want to reuse same page for `Create` / `Edit` data

But need to initial some default with the field is `null` / `undefined`

i don't want check the field is null in controller like

```
scope.user = {};
$scope.user.status = $scope.user.status || "some init value";
```

but i tried ng-init with no luck

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    
    <script>
      angular
        .module('testDefaultValue', [])
        .controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
          $scope.newUser = {}; 
          $scope.existingUser = { status: "Locked" };
        }]);
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="testDefaultValue" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <label>User Status:</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      ng-model="newUser.status"
      ng-init="newUser.status = 'Active' "
    />
    <br />
    Should be: Active
    <br />
    <br />
    
    <label>User Status:</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      ng-model="existingUser.status"
      ng-init="existingUser.status = 'Active' "
    />
    <br />
    Should be: Locked
    <br />
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the exact issue? What doesn't work as expected?

Comment: @devqon i want have a initial value when ng-model is null

Answer (score 0):

Would be better to initialize values in a controller. Use user model from the server when edit, or use model with default values on creating... And do it in the controller, not in html.

Comment: but the real case i need to previous page information to initial the default value

Answer (score 0):

Just set the variable that you use in ng-model to "Active" in your JavaScript code.

```
this.newUser.status = 'Active';
this.existingUser.status = 'Active';
```

Comment: Two lines of code and the problem is solved...That's probably the easiest solution.

Comment: in real case have too much checking before assign this variable (i.e: if field not null), so i don't think this is easiest.